# Unable to convert MongoDB collection to list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to iterate a MongoDB collection and convert it into a list. But the array list is always empty. Here is the code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

getPost: function(callback){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
        var cursor = db.collection('post').find();
        var list = [];
        cursor.forEach(function(doc){
            list.push(doc);
        });
        callback(list);
    })
}
```

`list` is always `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    db.collection('post', function (err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function (err, list) {
            callback(list);
        });
    });
});
```